# Different configuration for run and run-war

Tags: maven, configuration, jetty, maven-jetty-plugin

is it possible to have to configurations of jetty? I mean situation such as this:
if I've started jetty with jetty:run, do this [ different webAppDirecotry ] if I've typed jetty:run-war, do something else, for example set scanIntervalSeconds to 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with Maven profiles. Define your plugin's settings in there and trigger the profiles.

Comment: Define the settings per `<goal/>` explicitly in your plugin's settings by having separate `<execution/>`-s.

Comment: does the recognition of this goal is automatic?